# How can I make a button with delete and a link together?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a button to go to a link, but when the visitor is the user that created the page, that button needs to also have an X so it can be deleted by the user-owner.

1) Tags: The solution that works has the problem that: I can make the 2 buttons, but it is difficult to spot visually which X corresponds with each button (when there is more than one).

2) Tags: On the other side, when I put them together you can not click on the X, because it always takes you to the buttons' link.

NEED: I need a button with two parts, one for the delete X and another for the link of the text, but I do not see how to do it. Please, see the image.

```
<div class="g-mb-30">
<h6 class="g-color-gray-dark-v1">
        <button id="jh-create-entity"
        *ngIf="owner === post.userId" 
        class="btn btn-primary float-right jh-create-entity create-tag"
        [routerLink]="['/tag/new']" [queryParams]="{ 'postIdEquals': post.id }">
        <fa-icon [icon]="'plus'"></fa-icon>
    </button>
<strong class="g-mr-5">Tags:</strong>
<span  *ngFor="let tag of post.tags">
    <a (click)="removePostTag(tag.id, post.id)">
        <fa-icon [icon]="'times'"></fa-icon>
    </a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/tag', tag.id, 'view' ]" class="u-tags-v1 g-font-size-12 g-brd-around g-brd-gray-light-v4 g-bg-primary--hover g-brd-primary--hover g-color-black-opacity-0_8 g-color-white--hover rounded g-py-6 g-px-15 g-mr-5">
        {{tag.tagName}}
    </a>
</span>
</h6>


<h6 class="g-color-gray-dark-v1">
        <button id="jh-create-entity"
        *ngIf="owner === post.userId" 
        class="btn btn-primary float-right jh-create-entity create-tag"
        [routerLink]="['/tag/new']" [queryParams]="{ 'postIdEquals': post.id }">
        <fa-icon [icon]="'plus'"></fa-icon>
    </button>
    <strong class="g-mr-5">Tags:</strong>
    <span  *ngFor="let tag of post.tags">
        <a [routerLink]="['/tag', tag.id, 'view' ]" class="u-tags-v1 g-font-size-12 g-brd-around g-brd-gray-light-v4 g-bg-primary--hover g-brd-primary--hover g-color-black-opacity-0_8 g-color-white--hover rounded g-py-6 g-px-15 g-mr-5">
        <span>
            <a (click)="removePostTag(tag.id, post.id)">
                <fa-icon [icon]="'times'"></fa-icon>
            </a>
        </span>    
            {{tag.tagName}}
        </a>
    </span>
</h6>
```

[image]

EDIT Wayne: This does not work since the X (delete) does not work

```
                          <h6 class="g-color-gray-dark-v1">
                            <button id="jh-create-entity"
                                *ngIf="owner === post.userId" 
                                class="btn btn-primary float-right jh-create-entity create-tag"
                                [routerLink]="['/tag/new']" [queryParams]="{ 'postIdEquals': post.id }">
                                <fa-icon [icon]="'plus'"></fa-icon>
                            </button>
                            <strong class="g-mr-5">Tags:</strong>
                            <section style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around;">
                            <span  *ngFor="let tag of post.tags">
                                <a [routerLink]="['/tag', tag.id, 'view' ]" class="u-tags-v1 g-font-size-12 g-brd-around g-brd-gray-light-v4 g-bg-primary--hover g-brd-primary--hover g-color-black-opacity-0_8 g-color-white--hover rounded g-py-6 g-px-15 g-mr-5">
                                <span>
                                    <a (click)="removePostTag(tag.id, post.id)">
                                        <fa-icon [icon]="'times'"></fa-icon>
                                    </a>
                                </span>    
                                    {{tag.tagName}}
                                </a>
                            </span>
                            </section>
                        </h6>
```

Comment: for the second option, have you thought about adding a higher z-index for the "x" so that it sits on top of everything. This will allow the "x" to be clicked and the button to be clicked - separately. `style="z-index: 100"`

Comment: This seems like a question that would fit better on [ux.se], since it appears to be about the *design* of the UI rather than *coding* the UI.

Comment: May be your are right. How can I move it to the User Experience? Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sunny. I does both actions at the same time: deletes and links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, in your second solution (which I recommend from a UX standpoint), you have the X icon within the  element that links to /tag.

If you move that icon to the outside of your anchor, it should work properly.

Check my quick example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

    <section style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around;">
      <span style="border: 1px solid gray; padding: 5px;">
        <a onclick="remove()"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
        <a onclick="link()">Link</a>
      </span>
      <span style="border: 1px solid gray; padding: 5px;">
        <a onclick="remove()"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
        <a onclick="link()">Link</a>
      </span>
      <span style="border: 1px solid gray; padding: 5px;">
        <a onclick="remove()"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
        <a onclick="link()">Link</a>
      </span>
      <span style="border: 1px solid gray; padding: 5px;">
        <a onclick="remove()"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
        <a onclick="link()">Link</a>
      </span>
    </section>

  </body>
  <script>
    function remove() {
      alert('Removed an element!');
    }

    function link() {
      alert('Clicked a link!');
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Edit: Changed to use FA so that it is hopefully more clear.

Edit: Here is an example of how you would apply what I am explaining in your own code. If this does not work, inspect your CSS.

```
<h6 class="g-color-gray-dark-v1">
  <button id="jh-create-entity" *ngIf="owner === post.userId" class="btn btn-primary float-right jh-create-entity create-tag"
    [routerLink]="['/tag/new']" [queryParams]="{ 'postIdEquals': post.id }">
    <fa-icon [icon]="'plus'"></fa-icon>
  </button>
  <strong class="g-mr-5">Tags:</strong>
  <section style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around;">
    <span *ngFor="let tag of post.tags">
      // Note that here I have moved the X link to be a child of the span
      <a (click)="removePostTag(tag.id, post.id)">
        <fa-icon [icon]="'times'"></fa-icon>
      </a>
      // The tag name link is on the same level as the X (child of the span)
      <a [routerLink]="['/tag', tag.id, 'view' ]" class="removed-classes">
        {{tag.tagName}}
      </a>
    </span>
  </section>
</h6>
```

Comment: Hi Wayne, Thanks, but I do not see how your solution makes a difference between both actions in the same button. Please, check the image above. In the first case, the case and the other link are away from each other, but you can see both... the problem appears when they are in the same button. I need a button with two parts, one for the delete X and another for the link of the text, but I do not see how to do it.

Comment: Does my edit make more sense? If you run the code snippet, you'll see four distinct 'buttons' that have both an X icon (for deleting the tag) and 'Link' text which is your tag text. Do you need the _entire_ bordered area to link to the tag? If so, that is slightly different but can be done too.

Comment: Thanks Wayne. It does not work. May be because I can not play with all that CSS that is from a template. I think I need some kind of button with two parts really differenciated. And I see that yours works in the snippet. May be I'm missing something.